# Objective-C Xcode: Tableview detailitem empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm doing this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/1845/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-2) to get the hang of ios development, but now I'm stuck.

It's probably just a little thing, but when I get in my detailView's method 'setDetailItem', the **newDetailItem** variable is empty (see screenshot).

I have no idea why this is, but in the tutorial this seems to get automatically filled.

Why is it empty and how do I get the right detailItem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post text instead of image. It's more readable that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the tutorial and a sample code is provided by them.It works fine with the memory.It is a setter method which is called when you provide the value like this

```
  DetailViewController *detailController =segue.destinationViewController;
  ScaryBugDoc *bug = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
  detailController.detailItem = bug;
```

check weather you are passing in valid memory value (here bug).if you give it nil then yeah there may be no memory

Comment: Ah, yes. As simple as that. Thanks!